# Black square at the end of footnote

Tags: footnotes

I have a problem with footnote inside parcol. I'm trying to remove the black square at the end of the text of the footnote. The text is the following:

```
Pro angusilis\footnote{emend. \textit{angustiis}.} mortem homines
quaerentes, qui nimium utique gratulantur,[...]
```

and here the results, what's wrong with this?

[image]

I'm using overleaf.

**Edit:** As you requested here the document that reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=italian, latin]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin, bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \subsection*{Commento interlineare}
    this is first text\footnote{this is the footnote}
    \switchcolumn
    \subsection*{}
    this is first text
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example code?

Comment: As JouleV says, without code to reproduce this, we cannot say anything

Comment: I don't think Overleaf is the problem here, therefore I'll remove the Overleaf tag. It might be the editor you're using, but the question is not really about Overleaf or its behaviour.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If I remember well, both `paracol` and `footmisc` define `\footnotelayout`, and their definitions don't agree.